# Can you take the derivative of the normal unit vector in n-t coordinate system?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

In class we are looking at rotation about a fixed axis. Using the n-t coordinate system, the notes derive the acceleration like:

(1) $a= \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d\omega}{dt}{\bf{r_p}} + \omega\frac{d{\bf{r_p}}}{dt}$

(2) $a= \alpha {\bf{r_p}} + \omega(\omega{\bf{r_p}})$

I do not understand how the time derivative of the vector r suddenly becomes $\omega{\bf{r_p}}$

Now, the way I have tried to go from (1) to (2) in the following way:

$ \omega\frac{d{\:\bf{r_p}}}{dt}$

since the vector r is equal to the magnitude of r times the vector in the normal direction;

$ \omega\frac{d{\:(r\:\bf{e_n}})}{dt}$

using the product  rule to take the derivative;

$ \omega( r\:\frac{d{\bf{e_n}}}{dt}\:\:+ \:\:\frac{dr}{dt}{\bf{e_n}})$

but then I get stuck because I don't know if you can take the derivative of a unit vector in n-t coordinates. You can in polar coordinates but since the origin follows the particle in n-t im not sure what this means intuitively.

I've also tried using chain rule to take the derivative of vector r which leaves me with the derivative of vector r with respect to an angle theta... which also left me dead ended.

I doubt the way I've written this makes sense - I'm pretty confused at this point.

Comment: okay so i think i may have answered my own question... if the vector r is the position vector then the change in position r wrt time is the velocity v, which by definition is equal to the angular rotation times the position. Can't believe I've been stuck on this for at least 2 hours.